# Node.js http request inside loop

Tags: node.js

I am trying to periodically load some data from external API like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  getData();
}, 60000);

function getData() {
  if (typeof someObject.data === 'object') {
    for (var prop in someObject.data) {
      if (prop === 1 || prop === 2) {
        var options = {
          host: 'somehost.com',
          path: '/somepath?param=' + prop
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
          // EXECUTION NEVER REACHES THIS POINT ?!?!
          req.on('end', function() { alert('ended'); });
        });
        req.end();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I do not do any intervals and loops, such request to the same host works perfectly. However, if I try to do something like shown above, then the request never ever calls its callback function.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your variables (someobject) is not in scope (undefined ),have you tried debugging it line by line, and see if everything is defined?

Comment: In fact, I have a check `typeof someObject === 'object'` as well, I just didn't include it here for better readability. It reaches the line where the request is made but it never returns. If I remove the other stuff (setInterval and the loop), everything executes perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your conditions are bad, the following works fine for me.

```
var http = require('http');

setInterval(function() {
  getData();
}, 1000);

function getData() {
  console.log('get');
  //if (typeof someObject.data === 'object') {
    console.log('get 1');
    //for (var prop in someObject.data) {
      console.log('get 2');
      //if (prop === 1 || prop === 2) {
        console.log('get 3');
        var options = {
          host: 'google.com',
          path: '/'
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
          console.log('http request', res.statusCode);
          //req.on('end', function() { 
          //  console.log('ended', req); 
          //});
        });
        req.end();
      //}
    //}
  //}
}
```

also If I'm right, you don't need `req.on('end')`, the callback of the request is called when it's completed. You can also use `http.get`, so you don't need to call `req.end`

```
    var req = http.get( options.host, function(res) {
      console.log('http request', res.statusCode);
      //req.on('end', function() { 
      //  console.log('ended', req); 
      //});
    }).on('error', function( e ) {
      console.error( 'error', e );
    })
```

see more info in the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

hope I could help.

Comment: Yep, seems to be related to the environment / other parts of code. Isolated test runs well. Thanks.

Comment: You can simplify your code with some modules. Take a look at async https://github.com/caolan/async and request https://github.com/mikeal/request